# Cannot resume state in Hyper-V on a Macrium viBoot image

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v, macrium

I am trying to run a VM using Hyper-V from a Macrium mrimg file. I can successfully boot up a VM from this image using Hyper-V, and log into the machine on my corporate domain, so this works great.

However, once the VM is shut down, I can't restart it. I keep getting the message:

> **The application encountered an error while attempting to change the state of 'Mark Virtual Machine'**
>
> Checkpoint operation failed.
>
> Production checkpoints cannot be created.
>
> Cannot take checkpoint.
>
> ...

[image]

Is there a way to be able to stop and start the Hyper-V VM coming from a Macrium image?

Comment: What options did you use when setting up the VM (generation, disk types, etc.)  Do you have any pass-through disks setup in the VM?  How are you shutting down the VM?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 the VM is created in Macrium viBoot. The options in there are not the same as those in Hyper-V. I was able to change the Name, Startup RAM, number of processors, and network adapter. In Hyper-V it shows that a SCSI controller hosts a virtual hard drive. I shut down the first VM by clicking "Save". The second VM was shut down by a power outage over the weekend. Both "methods" resulted in the same situation described above.